# Transições e atualização da página

Tags: html, css, css-hover, transição

Eu estou aprendendo css agora através de sites e cursos. Quando eu crio um elemento e quero fazer hover nele, eu coloco transition no elemento. A questão é: Quando eu atualizo minha página (f5), o elemento é mostrado e depois desaparece. É como um estado inicial que na verdade não é inicial.

Exemplo bem claro: Eu falo pro meu css que quero margin e padding 0 no html. Até aí tudo bem. Aí eu crio uma nav bar e falo que ela tem 20 de margin e padding (exemplo). Se eu colocar transição nela de .2s, quando eu atualizar a página eu consigo ver ela saindo do estado 0 e indo ao 20 em .2s. Como resolver isso? Se eu entendesse como isso funciona, poderia resolver todos os outros elementos que estão com o mesmo problema

Vou colocar a parte da nav que eu estou tendo problema. Quando eu atualizo a página, eu consigo ver o transition da border-bottom dela. (antes de dar o hover)

```css
body {
  font-family: "Roboto", "Arial", sans-serif;
}

*, *::before, *::after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: inherit;
  color: #4a4a4a;
}

html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #4a4a4a;
  background-color: #fff;
}

body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 1.6em;
}

.header {
  height: 116vh;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)), url(https://placecage.com/200/200);
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}
.header__bar-top {
  background-color: #3eafc2;
  height: 5px;
}
.header__nav {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 15px 20px;
}
.header__nav ul {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px 40px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  list-style: none;
}
.header__nav__logo {
  height: 40px;
  width: 200px;
  background-image: url("../img/color4.png");
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-image 0.4s;
}
.header__nav__list {
  float: right;
  padding: 13px;
}
.header__nav__list li {
  margin-right: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.header__nav__list li:last-of-type {
  margin-left: 30px;
}
.header__nav__list li a:link, .header__nav__list li a:visited {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgba(238, 238, 238, 0.5);
  padding-bottom: 8px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
  transition: border-bottom 0.2s, color 0.1s;
}
.header__nav__list li a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
}

.sobre {
  background-color: #eee;
  height: 100vh;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 75%, 0 100%);
  text-align: right;
}
.sobre__img {
  height: auto;
  width: 80vh;
  padding-top: 50px;
}

.conhecimentos__img {
  margin-bottom: -3px;
  height: 300px;
}

.objetivos {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #eee;
}

/*# sourceMappingURL=style.css.map */
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,400i,500,700" rel="stylesheet">

<header id="inicio" class="header">
 <div class="header__bar-top"></div>

 <nav class="header__nav">
  <a href="index.html">
   <div class="header__nav__logo"></div>
  </a>
  <ul class="header__nav__list">
   <li><a id="a" href="#inicio">Inicio</li></a>
   <li><a href="#sobre">Sobre</a></li>
   <li><a href="#conhecimentos">Conhecimentos</a></li>
   <li><a href="#portifolio">Portifólio</a></li>
   <li><a href="#objetivos">Objetivos</a></li>
   <li><a href="https://github.com/Alissin4444">Visualizar código</a></li>
  </ul>
 </nav>

 <div class="header__main">
  <span class="header__main__title"></span>
  <span class="header__main__sub"></span>
  <span class="header__main__button"></span>
 </div>

</header>

<section id="sobre" class="sobre">
 <h1>Bem, conheça um pouco sobre mim :)</h1>
 <span class="sobre__main">Texto aleatório, Texto aleatório, Texto aleatório, Texto aleatório</span>
</section>

<section id="conhecimentos" class="conhecimentos">
 <img class="conhecimentos__img" src="assets/img/skills1.png" alt="avatarSkills">
 <h2>Skills como desenvolvedor</h2>
</section>

<section class="portifolio">

</section>

<section class="objetivos">

</section>

<footer>

</footer>
```

Comment: Amigo se vc não editar a sua pergunta e incluir seu código CSS e HTML fica difícil te dar uma resposta concreta. Vc que que o elemento só se mova quando vc colocar o mouse encima dele? Ou vc quer que ao atualizar a página um elemento se mova até um ponto e pare, e depois ao fazer hover nele ele se mexa?

Comment: Eu quero que ele se mexa somente quando eu der hover nele. O problema é que ele se mexe sem eu querer, quando ele atualiza a página

Comment: Aqui ficou normal, não deu esse problema não! Só com esse pedaço que vc colocou ai não adiantou muito não pq não da para simular seu problema, acho que é melhor vc colocar o HTML e CSS da nav inteira

Comment: Vou colocar no github e enviar o link

Comment: https://github.com/Alissin4444/portifolio/blob/master/portifolio.rar

Comment: Vc tá falando da linha abaixo dos itens do menu que pisca e depois some?

Comment: Sim. Isso mesmo. Eu não entendi por que isso ocorre

Comment: Vlw Hugo. Vou olhar o código e entender oq havia feito de errado. Good wallpaper sdajsdak. Vlws

Comment: Uai vc conseguiu resolver o problema ai? Já arrumou a linha piscando?